# Суффиксы прилагательных

Tags: орфография

Здравствуйте! Почему с словах "безветренный" и "разломанный" пишется двойная НН?

Answer (score 2):

Прилагательное "ветреный" — слово-исключение. Появляется приставка — пишется 2 н /безветренный/. "Разломанный" — причастие; страдательное причастие с любой приставкой, кроме *не*, пишется с 2 н.

Comment: Танюша, следите, пожалуйста, за своей пунктуацией. Вы даете грамотные ответы, но мне приходится расставлять Вам кавычки, большие буквы и т.д.

Comment: Всенепременно!

Answer (score 0):

У всех прилагательных пишется -НН- в суффиксах -ЕНН, -ОНН, а не только потому, что в слове безветренный есть приставка (но не стоит путать со словами типа *осенний,* в них первая Н принадлежит корню, а вторая — суффикс). Поэтому ветреный и является исключением. Согласна, что наличие приставки, кроме НЕ- — это показатель удвоенной Н в причастии.

Answer (score 0):

С прилагательным "ветреный" именно так: добавляется приставка - слово уже не является исключением и пишется по правилу:безветренный (с двумя Н)

Answer (score 0):

§ 58. Двойные согласные пишутся при сочетании приставки и корня, если приставка кончается, а корень начинается одной и той же согласной, например: поддержать, преддверие, ввести, оттереть, ссыпать, восстановить, беззаконный, контрреволюция.

§ 59. Двойные согласные пишутся при сочетании составных частей сложносокращенных слов, если одна часть кончается, а другая начинается одной и той же согласной, например: Моссовет, главврач.

§ 60. Двойное н и двойное с пишутся при сочетании корня и суффикса, если корень кончается, а суффикс начинается согласной н или с:

с суффиксом -н-, например: длинный (длина), старинный (старина), каменный (камень), доменный (домна), законный (закон), временный (основа времен-);

с суффиксом -ск-, например: котласский (Котлас), арзамасский (Арзамас), русский (Русь), но: тартуский (Тарту), ханькоуский (Ханькоу);

с суффиксом -ств-: искусство (ср. искусный).

Двойное с пишется также в глаголах прошедшего времени при сочетании основ на -с с возвратной частицей -ся, например: спасся, несся.

Примечание. Двойное н пишется в числительном одиннадцать.

§ 61. Двойное н пишется в суффиксах -енн-, -онн- прилагательных, образованных от существительных, например: соломенный, болезненный, клюквенный, искусственный, внутренний, ведренный, свойственный, обеденный, революционный, позиционный.

Примечание. В слове ветреный и в производных от него пишется одно н, но в приставочных образованиях пишется -нн- (безветренный, подветренный).

Прилагательные с суффиксом -ян- (-ан-), образованные от существительных, пишутся с одним н, например: волосяной, дровяной, глиняный, кожаный. Прилагательные деревянный, оловянный, стеклянный пишутся с двойным н.

С одним н пишется суффикс -ин- в прилагательных, например: соловьиный, куриный, гостиный, а также в существительном гостиница.

§ 62. Двойное н пишется в страдательных причастиях прошедшего времени, например: читанные на торжественном заседании доклады; боец, раненный вражеской пулей; колхоз, организованный в 1930 году; усиленный двумя ротами отряд; депутаты, избранные в Верховный Совет.

§ 63. Двойное н пишется во всех прилагательных, образовавшихся из страдательных причастий прошедшего времени (или по их типу), если эти прилагательные имеют приставки либо оканчиваются на -ованный, -еванный (кроме жеваный и кованый), например: больному назначено усиленное питание, вышел том избранных сочинений Пушкина, возвышенный стиль, вписанный треугольник, выдержанное вино, доверенный человек, умеренный климат, изысканные манеры, отвлеченный вопрос, рассеянный ученик, поношенное платье, подержанные книги, заплаканное лицо, заржавленный ключ, рискованный шаг, балованный ребенок, корчеванный участок.

Но с одним н следует писать прилагательные, образовавшиеся из страдательных причастий прошедшего времени (в том числе и сложные, см. § 80, п. 2), если эти прилагательные не имеют приставки и не образованы от глаголов на -овать, -евать, например: ученые труды, раненые пограничники, рваная одежда, копченая колбаса, кипяченое молоко, вяленая рыба, гашеная известь, соленые огурцы, моченые яблоки, вареный картофель, гладкокрашеная ткань.

Слова желанный, священный, нечаянный, невиданный, неслыханный, нежданный и некоторые другие, определяемые в словарном порядке, пишутся с двумя н.

§ 64. Двойное н пишется в наречиях на -о и в существительных с суффиксами -ик, -иц-, -ость, образованных от прилагательных, если последние пишутся с двумя н, например: нечаянно, неслыханно, взволнованно, взволнованность (взволнованный); уверенно, уверенность (уверенный); воспитанность, воспитанник, воспитанница (воспитанный); ставленник (ставленный); пленник (пленный); именинник (именинный); сенник (сенной); коренник (коренной); свойственник (свойственный).

Если же прилагательное имеет одно н, то и образованные от него наречия и существительные пишутся с одним н, например: путано, путаник, путаница (путаный); учено, ученость (ученый); конопляник (конопляный); серебряник (серебряных дел мастер). Также с одним н пишутся слова сребреник (в значении монеты) и бессребреник (бескорыстный человек).

§ 65. Двойное н пишется во множ. ч. и в женском и среднем роде ед. ч. кратких прилагательных, образовавшихся от страдательных причастий прошедшего времени, в полной форме которых - двойное н, например: группы дисциплинированны и организованны; девочка воспитанна и умна; они очень рассеянны.

Краткие же страдательные причастия пишутся с одним н, например: сломан, сломана, сломано, сломаны; юноша воспитан комсомолом; девочка изнежена воспитанием; мы ограничены временем; ученики организованы в группу.

§ 66. Двойное ж пишется в словах вожжи, дрожжи, можжевельник, жужжать и в производных от них, а также в некоторых образованиях от глагола жечь, например: жжешь, жжет, жженый, жжение, жженка.

При наличии чередования зг - зж, зд - зж следует писать не двойное ж, а зж, например: брюзжать (брюзга), мозжечок (мозг), приезжать (приезд), позже (стар. поздо, соврем. поздно), загромозжу (загромоздить), а также брезжить (ср. стар. брезг - "рассвет").

§ 67. Не пишется больше двух одинаковых согласных подряд, хотя бы это и требовалось составом слова, например: рассориться (рас + ссориться), одесский (одесс + ский), прусский (прусс + ский), пятитонный (пятитонн + ный).

§ 68. Написание двойных согласных в иноязычных словах определяется в словарном порядке, например: ирригация, коррозия, кассация, эксцесс, эссенция, но: афиша, литера, официальный, офорт, рапорт.

§ 69. В словах, образованных от основ, оканчивающихся на две одинаковые согласные, двойные согласные перед суффиксами сохраняются, например: группа - группка, группочка; программа - программка, программный; киловатт - киловаттный; Калькутта - калькуттский; класс - классный; гунн - гуннский, балл (единица меры, оценки) - пятибалльный; галл - галльский; либретто - либреттист.

Но пишется: кристальный (хотя кристалл), финка, финский (хотя финн), колонка (хотя колонна), пятитонка (хотя тонна), оперетка (хотя оперетта).

Примечание. В первой части сложносокращенных слов, которая представляет собой основу, оканчивающуюся двойной согласной, пишется только одна согласная, например: грамзапись, групком.

Comment: Вы не могли бы писать покороче?